# Just move those files from one disk to another

Tags: windows, gratis, file-management

Copying and moving files with Windows Explorer is not reliable. Depending on what error you get, the action is interrupted and **does not continue**, even if you hit the "Skip" button. Here is an example I had several times during the last 2 weeks:

[image: 0x80004005 Unspecified error]

I am looking for a tool that

- moves files from one folder to another folder as the result of a drag'n'drop action like Windows Explorer
- is unstoppable, i.e. continues with the remaining files even in worst cases. Ideally it would even ask to reconnect the disk if the disk was accidentally ejected or had a power loss or other hardware failure
- asks to take over the permissions like Windows Explorer does with this dialog:

  [image: List item]
- is able to process system files like

  [image: Moving system files]
- works with NTFS (which has all these security features)
- works on Windows 10
- is gratis or less than 10 €

The tool may

- ask once but always provide a "do this for all items" checkbox

The tool needn't

- copy the permissions. It would be ok if the destination file is world-readable (like `0777` on Linux).

Ideally, the tool

- reads $MFT directly, like [Search Everything](https://www.voidtools.com/) or [WizTree](https://diskanalyzer.com/). (Because Windows is soooo slow in finding files)

Basically, I want to move **everything** that I drag'n'dropped without much asking. The disks that I process are old, damaged or in some other way hardly usable. If the file system is damaged so hard, I am gonna use other tools, which require much more skill and will thus cost

I know that moving causes write operations which is not ideal. But I need to know which files have been processed an which have not. A file no longer being on the source disk is a clear indicator for "was processed" in this scenario.

Why not use a backup tool? I will exclude a lot of folders like Program Files, Program Files(x86), Windows, ProgramData, ... What I do is data migration, not a backup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[FastCopy](https://fastcopy.jp/) does it and is super fast as well. The usability could be improved, but its speed is awesome! Where Windows Explorer moved files at 800 kB/s, FastCopy reached 60 MB/s.

For the requirements:

> moves files from one folder to another folder as the result of a drag'n'drop action like Windows Explorer

This is a bit tricky, because that functionality is not enabled by default. You need to set it in the options ("Shell Extension"):

[image: FastCopy Enable Shell Extension]

> is unstoppable, i.e. continues with the remaining files even in worst cases.

It copied the `History.IE5` folder without any issues.

According to [this German blog post](https://www.arsenal-of-wisdom.org/?p=973) it will even process files that are owned by TrustedInstaller.

> asks to take over the permissions

Not exactly. But it can run in normal or elevated mode.

> is able to process system files

In elevated mode definitively.

> works with NTFS

Yes, and you can even choose to copy permission information (ACL) and Alternate Data Streams (ADS)

> is gratis

[yes](https://fastcopy.jp/help/fastcopy_eng.htm#license), although no longer available as source